# Submitting a Spring Form in AJax is always null

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp

I am trying to submit a spring form via ajax but the values within the form are always coming across as null (The actual form is not null).

This is how I send the form from the JSP:

```
$('#fSystemSave').click(function() {
    $.post("/live-application/systemSave", {systemForm: $("#systemForm").serialize()}, displayModifiedSystemResults, "html");
});
```

This is the form:

```
<form:form id="systemForm" 
    method="post" action="/live-application/systemSave"
commandName="systemForm">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" align="left">
            <strong>SYSTEM SETTINGS</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                            
        <td valign="top">Name:&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top"><form:input path="fName" size="20" />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
         <td valign="top" align="left">
            <button type="button" id="fSystemSave">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

And this is the Java controller side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/systemSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveSystem(@ModelAttribute("systemForm") SystemForm systemForm, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

      logger.info("Save System1: " + systemForm);
      logger.info("Save System2: " + systemForm.getfName());
}
```

So 'Save System1' returns an Object tostring and 'Save System2' returns null. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Spring but I think `{systemForm: $("#systemForm").serialize()}` should just be `$("#systemForm").serialize()`.